# bash shell script, trouble creating mysql database plus user

Tags: mysql, bash, shell

I have a shell script which has the following content:

```
#!/bin/sh
mysql -uqgk_user -ppw12345 -e "create database qgk; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON qgk.* TO qgk_user@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'pw12345' WITH GRANT OPTION;"
```

I receive this error if I run the shell script:

```
manager@xagate:/var/www/.../public_html/...$ sh database_setup.sh 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'qgk_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I don't understand why this issue is occurring.  Anyone who posts a working solution for this issue can include their Ripple address within their answer to be rewarded XRP for their assistance with this issue.

Comment: Which of the two statements fails, or both?  either `qgk_user` is not permitted to create a database, or does not have `GRANT` privileges on that created database. Run them separately to find out which one fails. Also login as `qgk_user@localhost` and `SHOW GRANTS`.  Keep in mind that the `localhost` grants may possibly differ from `127.0.0.1` grants.

Comment: The script runs this command on one line.  Please clarify how to run the SQL separately by splitting this into two lines.

Comment: I mean to say, execute just the first statement, then the second to see which one fails `mysql -uqgk_user -ppw12345 -e "create database qgk"` -- does that succeed alone?

Comment: Check the output from `SHOW GRANTS` when logged in as `qgk_user` with that password. It appears you don't have permission to create your database. Also, I recommend deleting that comment ^^^ because it contains details about the host you're working on.

Comment: I can't login using the credentials, that's the problem.  It won't even tell me if I've actually even CREATED the user either by running mysql create user 'qgk_user'@'localhost'; because it just spits out mysql's help file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I solved this issue:

http://www.bluepiccadilly.com/2011/12/creating-mysql-database-and-user-command-line-and-bash-script-automate-process

```
manager@xagate:/var/www$ cat mysql_setup.sh 
#!/bin/bash

EXPECTED_ARGS=3
E_BADARGS=65
MYSQL=`which mysql`

Q1="CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $1;"
Q2="GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO $2@localhost IDENTIFIED BY '$3';"
Q3="GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON $1.* TO $2@localhost;"
Q4="FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
SQL="${Q1}${Q2}${Q3}${Q4}"

if [ $# -ne $EXPECTED_ARGS ]
then
 echo "Usage: $0 qgk qgk_user PASSWORD"
exit $E_BADARGS
fi

$MYSQL -uroot -p -e "$SQL"
```

I then had to login to Webmin an navigate to Servers > MySQL Database Server > User Permissions > root@localhost > reassigned the password.

When prompted for a password at the execution time of the mysql_setup.sh script and inputting the root@localhost user's password, the database was created along with the qgk_user and chosen password.

Thank you for your assistance, sir :)